# How set Multi Level Top Navigation Menu like master detail in oracle apex?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I have two Dynamic Menu Lists.(GL Module & Sales Module)

1 - Currently I'm using in which HMS is my application name and the menu populate using Dynamic List.

2 - I want to set the top menu lists based on Modules

3,4 - When ever I click on GL or Sales menu, only active module's menu should show as the picture described

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:
https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=145797:1

To do this, follow these steps:

1 - Go to shared components> Navigation> Lists.

2 - Create a list (LIST 1) with two entries (GL Module and Sales Module) set the start page for each of the entries.

3 - Create a second list (LIST 2) with all the pages (Controls, setup, report, etc).

4 - Go to "Edit Application Properties"> User Interface> Click on the pencil.

5 - On "Navigation Menu List" choose "LIST 2".

6 - On "Navigation Bar List" choose "LIST 1".

Now you need to know which page numbers belong to one module or another. Suppose pages 1 and 2 belong to GL Module. And pages 3 and 4 belong to Sales Module.

7 - Go back to shared components> Navigation> Lists> List 2. In each list item go to "Conditions", under "Condition Type" select "Current page is contained within expression 1 (comma delimited list of pages)". Then put the page groups of each list. "1,2" for GL module and "3,4" for Sales Module.

Comment: I have modified the answer given, it is possible to do something similar to what you want using only the apex.